# Can I install Ubuntu without losing Windows 8?

Tags: installation, libreoffice

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad U410 laptop running windows 8.1. I tried Ubuntu from a live USB and I liked it so much that I think I want to replace it as my OS.

I have two questions:

1. If I install Ubuntu completely, will I still keep windows/all my windows data?
2. How can I import my windows data to Ubuntu?(photos, videos, documents, apps, etc.)

also, how good is Libre Open Office? Is it worth trying to re-install the Windows office suite?

thanks :)

Comment: Ubuntu is far more better than windows! You can backup windows data(photos, videos etc) on external disk and install ubuntu completely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will keep windows and all your data if you select that option, when you turn on your computer the GRUB will ask what operative system you want to start, in my experience it's better if you have two hard disks or two partitions done before the installation, I tried to install Ubuntu and Windows 7 and the installation program had an error when creating the partition, so I recomend you to do so. You can import all your data from the another partition,from a usb pendrive or from internet,except your apps, some will have its version for Ubuntu and maybe you will have to look for some equivalent app. Libre Office is great, I used it before in Windows and now in Ubuntu and it works very well,it has improved a lot in the last years.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes you can install install Ubuntu without having to loose Windows or any of its DATA's only if you're installing to a separate/clean partition where Windows is not installed. Generally, Installing Ubuntu will only replace the GRUB (which is the boot loader for Linux) though it won't harm if you follow proper process. There are two methods to install Ubuntu, which are;

1. Install inside windows using [**Wubi**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows) (Unfortunately its not compatible with Win 8 & does not support 13.10)
2. Install onto a separate partition (I personally & most users would recommended this)

Assuming I've answered to the **point 1**;

I found this article about **[SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows/TransferringFilesAndSettings](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows/TransferringFilesAndSettings)**, which may interest you on how to transfer your files as in your **point 2**.

Libre Office is better but not like MS Office. Here's a [comparison](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Feature_Comparison%3a_LibreOffice_-_Microsoft_Office) between both. In any case, you need MS Office within Ubuntu, you may also achieve this by using [wine](http://www.winehq.org/), an application to run windows compatible programs within Ubuntu. Installation predeceases can be found by searching here within this community.

Hope this clears all your questions which is asked. Feel free to comment if there's anymore needs to be clarified.

Comment: thank you both for the help: I have tried to install Ubuntu from my USB, but it tells me that it cannot recognize any other OS on the computer. When I select "other", it takes me to the whole partition thingy, which I do not know anything about. Since I dont want to screw up my laptop, I got some help and made a new partition from my C drive (in Windows). I now have this space free, but I have no idea how to put Ubuntu on it, and nor did my helper.

Comment: I know Ubuntu is better(that is why I am switching), but I want to keep windows as a backup and because their are certain programs which I know do not have an Ubuntu version and are very important to me. Also, once I have Ubuntu installed, how easy will it be to switch between operating systems? thanks :)